# Like Jenkins, can TeamCity be notified by GIT when there is a commit?

Tags: git, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

When there is commit on git, I am want to initiate a build on that particular branch automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of handling commits - from Git server side and from client side.
If you want to handle commits immediately, you need to use GitHook. That is your code that is executed by Git server on special events (e.g. commit made).
That is handling from "server side".
Cons is that you increase the size of build queue, that is critical when you have an active development and big team.

From client side (including TeamCity and Jenkins) you have no other option than polling the server for changes.
Cons is that you don't have immediate response but that is a relative downside (you don't really need to catch changes done every second).
Pros is that you don't increase load on Git server.

That is a natural balance that doesn't relate to CI system. Both Jenkins and TeamCity work the same way.

Using CI system to start build right after each commit means polling frequently.
That is very bad since the load on VCS(Git) is very big.
Instead GitHook should be used.
That is a direct answer to your question.